# bash getting exit status from expect script

Tags: bash, tcl, wait, expect

Is there a special way to collect the exit status of the /home/casper/autoEXPscp.sh.  Because the debug mode is saying that the exit status is zero, but the file is not Ftp'd.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
blmnt="/home/casper/BlueMountain/"
ydate=$(date -d 'yesterday' "+%Y.%m.%d")
bfile="casper_BlueMountain_${ydate}.csv"

cd $blmnt

if [[ -e ${blmnt}${bfile} ]]; then
     /home/casper/autoEXPscp.sh
     result=$?
         if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then
             echo "Bluemountain scp is successful"
         else
             echo "Bluemountain scp failed"
         fi
else
   echo "${blmnt}${bfile} was not created "
   exit 1
fi
```

/home/casper/autoEXPscp.sh is an expect script (Yes I know - I need to get the keys exchanged - I work at a big company it takes weeks for the ssh group to exchange keys, and the client wants there reports NOW ).  Is there a special way to get the spawned command exit status from the expect script, and export it to the parent bash script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
    set ydate [exec date -d "yesterday" "+%Y.%m.%d"]
    set file "casper_BlueMountain_${ydate}.csv"
    spawn scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -oport=56050 $file casper@casper.com:/bluemountain/outgoing
    set pass "foo"
    expect {
    password: {send "$pass\r"; exp_continue}
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ydate [clock format [clock add [clock seconds] -1 day] "%Y.%m.%d"]
set file "casper_BlueMountain_${ydate}.csv"
set timeout -1
spawn scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -oport=56050 $file casper@casper.com:/bluemountain/outgoing
set pass "foo"
expect {password:}
send "$pass\r"
expect eof
lassign [wait] pid spawnid flag status
exit $status
```

notes:

1. expect is built on Tcl which has a very rich [`clock` command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm)
2. the default timeout is 10 seconds: I set the timeout to be infinite (-1) in case the file transfer takes a long time
3. I explicitly wait for the transfer to end (`expect eof`)

   - this may be the main problem in your code.
4. then you use the `wait` command to get the exit status. See the [`expect(1)` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/expect.1.html)

Comment: You could detect that the progress metering is still working and refresh the timeout that way…